# Recursively delete files with different names within directories - PHP

Tags: php, elgg

I'm using a script called ELGG. It allows my members to upload images to 4meg, but automatically reduces them to a defined size (700px wide or high). Unfortunately the huge images remain in the directories and this is choking my server. Several small images are produced in the process depending on whether it's a photo or avatar and I have to be careful I leave the right ones behind. It's not a busy site and I can run a small script weekly.

Here's where it get's tricky. The files I need to save are strangely numbered:

```
###large.jpg
###medium.jpg
###small.jpg
###tiny.jpg
###topbar.jpg
largethumb#####.jpg
smallthumb#####.jpg
thumb#####.jpg
```

The numbering ### seems to be random and varies from 2 digits to 20.

The files I need to delete will be names issued by my members but will also contain numerals issued by Elgg.

The script doesn't have to be fancy. It just needs to delete all files except the ones above in all sub directories.

Hopefully someone can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just [unlink()](http://ca2.php.net/unlink) the original after processing into thumbs...

Comment: It is open source so you can always look at the code. Also it may be worthwhile trying [Technical Support](http://community.elgg.org/groups/profile/179063/elgg-technical-support). I have not explored further but here is the link to the file upload code: http://reference.elgg.org/filestore_8php.html

Comment: @RyanVincent. Thanks for the reference link. It could be very handy to muggins. The Photo feature I'm using is a is a third party plugin. I've spoken to the developer, but he tels me it will be many months before he can do anything The photos are deliberately left there in case someone wants to download them. I have that feature turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scandir](https://www.php.net/scandir) to list All files inside the Directory.
Then, You can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to just select the files matching Your conditions.
Finally, [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) will delete the file You pass as argument.

You can also use [preg_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) also instead of preg_match.

Comment: I think the OP probably wants the inverse, what *don't* match his selected patterns.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I did modify the answer according to what You mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop with something like this into the directory:

```
$image = "pin987414578.png";
$delete = "pin987414578.png"; //keep original name to delete
$image2 = preg_replace("/[^a-z,A-Z.]/", "", $image);
if($image2=="large.png" ||$image2=="medium.png" ||$image2=="small.png" ||)
{
unlink($delete)
}
```

this sample= result: pin.png